# gridview boundfield width uncontrolled when text is long and wrapped

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where I have two long columns Primary_Skill and Resume_Title. I set the width of columns and wrap them as well but wrap is not going more than 2 lines and still the first two columns are appearing wider as comparison to what the width is set. Rest of columns are not displaying in the same screen. Below is my code.

```html
 <asp:GridView ID="grdSearchResult" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SeekerEmail_Id, Extension"
                        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="1px"
                        BackColor="White" CellPadding="5" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="Gray" Width="100%"
                        GridLines="Both">
                        <FooterStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White"></PagerStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="Green" Width="25%"></HeaderStyle>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Skills" DataField="Primary_Skill" SortExpression="Primary_Skill"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                                <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Resume Title" DataField="Resume_Title" SortExpression="Resume_Title"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Exp (Years)" DataField="Experience" SortExpression="Experience"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Location")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Location").ToString().Shorten(30) %>'
                                        Style="word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all; cursor: default;"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Post Date" DataField="Creation_Date" SortExpression="Creation_Date"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}">
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download Resume" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="lnkdownldUpdate" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" ToolTip='<%#Eval("SeekerEmail_Id")%>' Text='<%#Eval("SeekerEmail_Id").ToString().Shorten(30) %>'
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Resume_Title") %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" runat="server"
                                                Style="word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all; cursor: pointer;"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#008A8C"></SelectedRowStyle>
                        <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White"></RowStyle>
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

When column value is short then it is displaying fine but when it is long then it is not. Below is the screenshot. This is the whole screen I want to accommodate all columns in this screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify boundfield as below

```css
.grdSearchResultbreakword
{
  word-wrap:break-word;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Skills" DataField="Primary_Skill" SortExpression="Primary_Skill"
                        ItemStyle-Width="40%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="grdSearchResultbreakword"></asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a space between each job skills. Not `Java,J2EE` but `Java, J2EE`. If they are connected without a space the browser will see it as 1 single string and will put it on a single line. If there are spaces or `-` in a string it can wrap the words in the cell. Spring Framework has the first space in the whole string and that's why it goes to the second line at that point.

The same goes for Resume Title. The Word document with all the underscores will always be displayed in one line and will determine the minimal width of the column. Again this string cannot be wrapped in the cell. Either only display a fixed number of characters in that cell or put the content inside a `div` with the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: This is good but this is a user entered data and I should not manipulate it. I found another good option.